# Filter by a BIN in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering

So I created some bins on amounts in a pandas dataframe. I then want to filter by the bins to I do something like this:

```
df_ap['BINS'] == '(70000.0, 80000.0]'
```

This doesn't seem to work. I can clearly see that value in my dataframe. I copied it from the dataframe itself. I can groupby it, but I can't filter for that field. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you try `df_ap['BINS'].between(70000,80000)` ? or `df_ap['BINS'].astype(str)=='(70000.0, 80000.0]'`

Comment: since the bins you see are intervals and not actual strings , you may need to convert them to string first or use between

Comment: You're astype str worked great!

Comment: Glad it worked, you might also want to try @Jezrael answer below, its a good way for selecting intervals

Answer (score 3):

Compare by [`Interval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html):

```
df_ap = pd.DataFrame({'A':[90000,50000,75000.0]})
df_ap['BINS'] = pd.cut(df_ap['A'], bins=np.arange(0, 100000, 10000).astype(float))
print (df_ap)
         A                BINS
0  90000.0  (80000.0, 90000.0]
1  50000.0  (40000.0, 50000.0]
2  75000.0  (70000.0, 80000.0]

print (pd.Interval(left=70000, right=80000))
(70000, 80000]

mask = df_ap['BINS'] == pd.Interval(left=70000, right=80000)
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: BINS, dtype: bool
```